# Switching windows licenses during windows upgrade

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, virtualbox, license

I have a PC with a valid Windows 7 (box installation) license. On this PC, I have a virtualbox with a non-valid windows 7 license. I installed this for testing, but since I am going "productive" now, I want to do the following:

1. Upgrade the host PC to Windows 8.1. I have bought online a license for Windows 8.1 already.
2. Change the license on the virtualbox to the license of the host PC which will be available once I upgraded the host PC to 8.1

Is this possible without re-installing none of the two installations from scratch? Is there anything I have to observe when doing this? How do I upgrade a non-genuine windows 7 installation to a genuine without re-installing the system? Is that possible at all?

I used to always do these things from scratch but I am under time pressure now and cannot afford the time to install those from scratch.